# Runtime complexity of permutation function

Tags: time-complexity, runtime-analysis, recursion, backtracking, depth-first-search

I am trying to find the asymptotic run time complexity of the following function which will return a list of all permutations of nums.

```python
    def permute(nums):
        res = []
        dfs(nums, [], res)
        return res

    def dfs(nums, curr, res):
        if not nums:
            res.append(curr)
            return
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            dfs(nums[:i]+nums[i+1:], curr+[nums[i]], res)
```

I think that the run time on an input of size $n$ is $T(n)=nT(n-1)+n$ because the function will make $n$ recursive calls on an input of size $n-1$ and it loops over $n$ terms. This gives $T(n)\in \mathcal O(n!)$ but some people say that it is $\mathcal O(n\cdot n!)$. Is the runtime of this $\mathcal O(n!)$ or $\mathcal O(n\cdot n!)$?

Answer (score -1):

Consider this piece of code:

```
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            dfs(nums[:i]+nums[i+1:], curr+[nums[i]], res)
```

Note that `curr+[nums[i]]` creates a new list, and on the bottom level, each of the $n!$ new lists will have size $n$.
Hence $\mathcal{O} (n! \cdot n)$ total complexity.

On the other side, note that the complexity `nums[:i]+nums[i+1:]` is also linear in terms of $n$, but it does not present a problem, since its length at the bottom levels is $\mathcal{O} (1)$.

---

To look at it another way, the output has a size of $n! \cdot n$, so, barring any clever tricks in storing the output, the whole algorithm can't take less than that to produce the whole output.

---

In terms of recurrence relation, it gets a bit tricky, as the deeper we go, the larger the second argument (`curr`) gets.
So, perhaps we can write $T (n, \ell) = n \cdot T (n - 1, \ell + 1) + n \cdot (n + \ell)$, where $n$ is the length of `nums`, and $\ell$ is the length of `curr`. We are interested in $T (n, 0)$, and the base is $T (0, \ell) = \ell$.